# JavaScript/PHP: Redirecionamento de página

Tags: php, javascript, aplicação-web

Boa noite, eu sou um completo iniciante em desenvolvimento web, e após diversas pesquisas o google, não consegui uma resposta satisfatória.
Eu estou utilizando o comando `window.location.href` para redirecionar as páginas do meu sistema, porém como estão em localhost, estou apenas usando caminhos básicos, exemplo:
`window.location.href="../pages/pagina.php";` ou mesmo `window.location.href="pagina.php"`(quando estão no mesmo diretório).

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: ao subir para um servidor web, isso dará algum problema? Eu precisaria colocar o caminho completo, tipo "http://..."?
Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Não @RaphaelHenrique , ele irá funcionar sem problemas, só falta é adicionar ali uma barra `/` no segundo exemplo - `window.location.href="/pagina.php"` senão ele irá apenas acrescentar `pagina.php` no final do URL em vez de ir mesmo para a página, que será `dominio.com/pagina.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, a única situação que pode dar problema é se você estiver especificando o caminho desde o **começo**, exemplo `window.location.href = http://localhost/pagina`.

Enquanto você utiliza `../` (voltar diretório) ou então especificando uma página direto (sem barra no começo) ele vai ser relativo a **atual url**.

Exemplo:

- URL atual: http://seudominio.com.br/aplicacao/index.html

  - `window.location.href="../pages/pagina.php";` resulta em http://seudominio.com.br/pages/pagina.php
- URL atual: http://seudominio.com.br/aplicacao/index.html

  - `window.location.href="pagina.php"` resulta em http://seudominio.com.br/aplicacao/pagina.php